# Generate pandas dataframe from a Python's array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm working on a project using Python(3.6) in which I have an array of USA states and I want to generate a data frame with a column name `state` from that array.

Here's the array of USA States:

```
['NE', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'WD', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', `'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'WD', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'WD', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'NY', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'WD', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'LA', 'LA', 'DE', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'DE', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'DE', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'DE', 'LA', 'OK', 'OK', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'WD', 'WD', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'LA', 'ID', 'ID', 'OK', 'ID', 'LA', 'ID', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'OK', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'OK', 'ID', 'WD', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'OK', 'DE', 'WD', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'LA', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'LA', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NE', 'OK', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'SD', 'NE', 'NY', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'OK', 'NE', 'NE', 'OK', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'OK', 'NY', 'OK', 'NY', 'OK', 'UT', 'UT', 'UT', 'UT', 'UT', 'WD', 'OK', 'CO', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'CO', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'LA', 'ID', 'WD', 'ID\n', 'WD', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'WD', 'ID', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'SD', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'WD', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'WD', 'DE', 'DE', 'WD', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'WD', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'DE', 'DE', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'ID', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'DE', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'OK', 'LA', 'ID', 'OK', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'ID', 'OK', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'OK', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'ID', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'DE', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'SD', 'NY', 'NY', 'SD', 'NE', 'WD', 'NY', 'NE', 'OK', 'SD', 'NE', 'NE', 'NY', 'NE', 'OK', 'OK', 'NE', 'ID', 'NE', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'OK', 'NE', 'OK', 'NE', 'NE', 'WD', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'LA', 'OK', 'OK', 'UT', 'UT', 'UT', 'UT', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'WD', 'ID\n', 'LA', 'ID', 'ID', 'WD', 'NY', 'LA', 'ID\n', 'ID\n', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'WD', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'DE', 'DE', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'WD', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'WD', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'ID', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'ID', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'DE', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'DE', 'DE', 'LA', 'LA', 'DE', 'ID', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'ID', 'LA', 'OK', 'OK', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'ID', 'OK', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'OK', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'OK', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'OK', 'WD', 'WD', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'OK', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'OK', 'NY', 'NE', 'NY', 'NY', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NY', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'OK', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'LA', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'ID', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'OK', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'WD', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'OK', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'UT', 'UT', 'OK', 'UT', 'UT', 'UT', 'UT', 'UT', 'OK', 'OK', 'WD', 'OK', 'OK', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'NY', 'LA', 'ID\n', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'ID\n', 'WD', 'LA', 'ID', 'NY', 'WD', 'SD', 'WD', 'WD', 'ID\n', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'SD', 'DE', 'DE', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'WD', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'WD', 'NY', 'ID', 'WD', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'LA', 'DE', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'DE', 'ID', 'DE', 'LA', 'LA', 'DE', 'OK', 'ID', 'LA', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'OK', 'LA', 'WD', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'ID', 'WD', 'ID', 'LA', 'WD', 'OK', 'ID', 'LA', 'ID', 'DE', 'OK', 'OK', 'LA', 'OK', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'SD', 'NY', 'SD', 'NE', 'SD', 'NE', 'NY', 'NE', 'CO', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'WD', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'UT', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'OK', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'LA', 'NE', 'NE', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'NE', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'OK', 'UT', 'UT', 'UT', 'UT', 'UT', 'OK', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'WD', 'WD', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'LA', 'WD', 'ID', 'LA', 'ID', 'WD', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'ID', 'SD', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'WD', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'WD', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'WD', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'WD', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'ID', 'ID', 'ID', 'WD', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'WD', 'NY', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'DE', 'NY', 'DE', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'DE', 'ID', 'DE', 'DE', 'LA', 'LA', 'OK', 'ID', 'OK', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'WD', 'ID', 'LA', 'OK', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'ID', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'LA', 'ID', 'ID', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'ID', 'WD', 'LA', 'ID', 'ID', 'WD', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'DE', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'DE', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'WD', 'LA', 'LA', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'WD', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'NY', 'OK', 'NY', 'OK', 'CO', 'OK', 'OK', 'NE', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'NE', 'NE','WD', 'WD', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'WD', 'ID\n', 'ID', 'NY', 'SD', 'LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'NY', 'NY', 'LA', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD', 'WD']`
```

**Problem:** 
How Can I generate panda's data frame from this array because I need to calculate the percentage of each state in this array, how can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing like `value_counts` + `normalize`

```
pd.DataFrame({'State':l}).State.value_counts(normalize=True)
Out[893]: 
WD      0.206635
NY      0.186256
LA      0.178199
ID      0.160190
DE      0.075829
CO      0.074882
NE      0.063033
OK      0.035071
UT      0.010427
SD      0.005687
ID\n    0.003791
Name: State, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Needs it in the form of integers.

Comment: @jezrael ummm yep , you are right , but he mentioned dataframe :-)

Comment: is there any way to get the name of `states` existing in the array as a separet array?

Comment: @AbdulRehman pd.DataFrame({'State':l}).State.value_counts(normalize=True).reset_index()

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively simple, `pandas` reads dictionary as if they're columns, so you can do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'state': your_array})
```

To use pandas to count your states:

```
df['state'].value_counts()
# output:

WD      436
NY      393
LA      376
ID      338
DE      160
CO      158
NE      133
OK       74
UT       22
SD       12
ID\n      8
```

However, a potentially better way to do this without pandas might be:

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter(your_array)
percents = {k: float(v)/len(l) * 100 for k, v in d.items()}
```

Result:

```
{'CO': 7.488151658767772,
 'DE': 7.5829383886255926,
 'ID': 16.018957345971565,
 'ID\n': 0.37914691943127965,
 'LA': 17.819905213270143,
 'NE': 6.303317535545023,
 'NY': 18.62559241706161,
 'OK': 3.5071090047393367,
 'SD': 0.5687203791469194,
 'UT': 1.042654028436019,
 'WD': 20.66350710900474}
```

Comment: Hi @Rocky Li, how can I calculate the percentage for each `state` from this array or DataFrame?

Comment: Edited, @AbdulRehman, I don't think the best way to count your array would be using `Pandas`, so I did it in another way, if you use pandas, you can use `value_counts()`